# How to add value to array in php

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$size_arr = array(35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
```

And this is phpmyadmin

[image: datatable]

```
$result = array();
$data = array(); // query get from table
foreach ($data as $row) {
  $result [$row->product_id][] = array($row->color => array($row->size));
}
var_dump($result);
```

How to add more value size to result array

```
array(
   [1] => array(
      'Black' => array(35 => 0, 36 => 40, 37 => 5, 38 => 0, 39 => 20), 
      'White' => array(35 => 0, 36 => 8, 37 => 12, 38 => 20, 39 => 0)
   )
)
```

Comment: Don't quite see what you try to do here, but something like: `print_r(array_replace(array_fill_keys($size_arr, 0), $DBvalues));`?

Comment: Your code does not produce the shown output.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply by adding the colour and row size as sub array keys

```
$result = array();
$data = array(); // query get from table
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $result [$row->product_id][$row->color][$row->size] = $row->quantity;
}
var_dump($result);
```